# How to turn-off Eclipse pydev code-analysis error/warning labels directly in text?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

After updating Eclipse to 4.18, and PyDev to 9.0.1, an unpleasant visual feature appeared with warnings displayed not only in line-number-margin (as before), but directly in the program text. How to disable it and leave error markers only on line-number-margin?

[image: text-editor screenshot]

Comment: Does in the preferences _General > Editors > Text Editors_ for _Show code minings for problem annotations:_ choosing _None_ solve your issue? By the way, 4.18 is three releases behind.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to *howlger*, that's the "Show code minings for problem annotations" checkbox in preferences:

[image]